# Как полностью сбросить все настройка терминала Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, консоль, kali-linux

Недавно решил немного поковыряться в настройках внешнего вида терминала kali, вроде ничего особо не поменял и вернул все в исходное состояние, но отображение серьезно изменилось в худшую сторону
Вот несколько примеров

Во первых текстовый курсор стал какой-то узкий и весь текст тоже сузился
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще когда я работаю в NeoVim он часто не стирает удаленный текст, примера нет так как не смог искусственно создать эту ситуацию
Некорректно отображаются выравнивающие текст отступы, наприм при команде ls:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше названия папок выводились столбиками ровно друг под другом

Вот, в общем что-то видимо я сломал
Подскажите как мне решить эту проблему если кто-то с ней сталкивался.
Или если вы знаете как вернуть все настройки терминала к исходному состоянию, тоже буду очень благодарен!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить в терминале команду `stty sane`

Comment: В `~/.config` смотрел? Как терминал-то называется?

Comment: `sitty sane` ничего не изменил

Comment: В `~/.config` посмотрел, нашел папку `qterminal.org` там есть файл `qterminal.ini`, но если его переименовать или удалить, то при открытии терминала, он восстанавливает этот файл с теми же настройками что и были, то есть ничего не поменялось